# tikz - alter circular path with nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to generate a circular path with nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1) at (8,6) {A11};
\node (2) [below left of = 1] {B22};
\node (3) [below right of = 2] {C33};
\node (4) [below right of = 1] {D44};
% connect the dots
\path[->,>=stealth]
(1) edge [bend right] node[left] {} (2)
(2) edge [bend right] node[left] {} (3)
(3) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (4)
(4) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, something doesn't seem quite right here, I think it doesn't look right due to the  arrows not being quite long enough. I gather this is most likely due to the nodes being too large to accommodate a circular path for the arrows, but I was hoping someone might have a work around for this issue? Please note that this is included in a larger diagram so its size must remain relatively small. Also I realize I can reduce the entire font size which seems the produce a better outcome by

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
```

Comment: Bend right option is not exactly a circular pattern and arrowheads visually alter the path they are drawn on. You can add this `\node[circle,minimum size=1.414cm,draw] (a) {};
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {A,...,D}{\node[fill=white] at (a.90*\xi){\x\xi\xi};}
` and compare the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following approximation is good enough. I also added a true circle (in pink) for comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=1pt}]
  \node (1) at (8,6) {A11};
  \node (2) [below left of = 1] {B22};
  \node (3) [below right of = 2] {C33};
  \node (4) [below right of = 1] {D44};
  % True circle
  \draw[red, opacity=.3] ($(1)!.5!(3)$) circle (6.5mm);
  % connect the dots
  \path[->,>=stealth]
  (1) edge [bend right=20]  (2)
  (2) edge [bend right=20]  (3)
  (3) edge [bend right=20]  (4)
  (4) edge [bend right=20]  (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, especially if you don't need to 'tweak' the diagrams, you might care to try Claudio Fiandrino's [`smartdiagram`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) package (available in TeX Live).

Here's a very simple example, with absolutely no tuning, but, I think, surprisingly compact for a LaTeX answer:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{A11,B22,C33,D44}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can alter the colours, shapes, etc. -- the details are in the manual.

[image]