# Multipart graph with linear and circular node patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, circles

I'm trying to draw a graph (PDF output of code below attached) that's a linear process, with a potentially circular element in it.

As you may see in the upper picture, the the B,C,D elements aren't in a circle. In the lower picture, they are but the method I used seems a bit kludgy (evidenced by the arc connecting the circle nodes.

Two questions:

1. What's a best way to draw the circle with the B, C, D nodes?
2. How do I get that circle "subgraph"(?) to be placed with the A, E, and spectrum nodes?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\tikzstyle{stage}=[draw, circle, align=center, text width=2.5cm, minimum height=2em%]
\tikzstyle{connectR}=[->,thick]
\tikzstyle{connectA}=[->,thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm, auto]
\node (id) [stage] {A};
\node (acquire) [stage, below right of=id] {B};
\node (assess) [stage, right of=acquire] {C};
\node (assdet) [right of=assess, text width=3.5cm, node distance=4.25cm ] {Some explanation};
\node (persuade) [stage, below left of=assess] {D};
\node (optexp) [stage, below of=persuade]{E};
\node (spect) [below of=optexp, rectangle, draw, fill, left color=white, right color=gray,minimum height=1cm, minimum width=5cm] {Outcome spectrum};

\draw [connectR] (id) -- (acquire);
\draw [connectR] (acquire) -- (assess);
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,mirror,raise=55pt}, very thick, ] (assdet.north) -- (assdet.south);
\draw[connectR,bend left] (assess.south) -- (persuade.east);
\draw[dashed, bend left] (persuade.west) -> (acquire.south);
\draw[connectR] (persuade) -- (optexp);
\draw [dashed] (optexp.south west) -- ($(spect.north west) +(.5,0)$) -- ($(spect.north east) +(-.5,0)$) -- (optexp.south east) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (one)[stage] at ({145}:4cm) {B};
\node (two) [stage] at ({35}:4cm) {C};
\node (three)[stage] at ({270}:4cm) {D};
\draw [->] (one.north) to [bend left=45] (two.north);
\draw [->] (two.east) to [bend left=45] (three.east);
\draw [->, dashed] (three.west) to [bend left=45] (one.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by including a minimal working example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in your question. An MWE begins with `\documentclass{...}` and the required `\usepackage`'s, and ends with `\end{document}`. It is much easier for us to help you if we can copy your example code and compile it without changing it ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we draw an invisible circle node that will guide us when placing B, C and D:

```
\node (x) [circle,below right=6cm of id,minimum size=5.5cm,anchor=center]{};
```

The next step is to place BCD with respect to our `x` node using border anchors:

```
\node (acquire) [stage,fill=white] at (x.135){B};
\node (assess) [stage,fill=white] at (x.45){C};
\node (persuade) [stage,fill=white] at (x.270){D};
```

Finally we will draw the arrows between BCD. Since the arrow caps will not be placed at the end of the paths, we need to load the `decorations.markings` library and set our decoration template:

```
arrowmark/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{stealth}}}
```

and now we can draw the arrows:

```
\draw[postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.4}](x.110)to[bend left=45](x.20);
\draw[postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.9}](x.20)to[bend left=45](x.290);
\draw[dashed,postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.95}](x.250)to[bend left=45](x.160);
```

I'm using border anchors again to draw the arrows (almost) exactly where the invisible `x` circle is. You can add a `draw` option to `x` to see that we are actually following the original circle.

### Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,calc}

\tikzstyle{stage}=[draw, circle, align=center, text width=2.5cm, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{connectR}=[->,thick]
\tikzstyle{connectA}=[->,thick]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm, auto,arrowmark/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{stealth}}}]
\node (id) [stage] {A};
\node (x) [circle,below right=6cm of id,minimum size=5.5cm,anchor=center]{};
\draw[postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.4}](x.110)to[bend left=45](x.20);
\draw[postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.9}](x.20)to[bend left=45](x.290);
\draw[dashed,postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.95}](x.250)to[bend left=45](x.160);
\node (acquire) [stage,fill=white] at (x.135){B};
\node (assess) [stage,fill=white] at (x.45){C};
\node (assdet) [right of=assess, text width=3.5cm, node distance=4.25cm ] {Some explanation};
\node (persuade) [stage,fill=white] at (x.270){D};
\node (optexp) [stage, below of=persuade]{E};
\node (spect) [below of=optexp, rectangle, draw, fill, left color=white, right color=gray,minimum height=1cm, minimum width=5cm] {Outcome spectrum};

\draw [connectR] (id) -- (acquire);
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,mirror,raise=55pt}, very thick, ] (assdet.north) -- (assdet.south);
\draw[connectR] (persuade) -- (optexp);
\draw [dashed] (optexp.south west) -- ($(spect.north west) +(.5,0)$) -- ($(spect.north east) +(-.5,0)$) -- (optexp.south east) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I'll be better about MWE next time.

Comment: Where are the steps you use

*  to create the BCD positioning
*  the arrow connecting steps

documented?

Comment: @Nate you may want to search the TikZ manual for "border anchor". Take also a look at this question where you can find a similar problem with some alternative approaches: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100691/tikz-alter-circular-path-with-nodes