# Place additional nodes when using smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I am trying to add additional nodes either side of a diagram produced using `smartdiagram`. Ideally, I would like node `b1` placed to the left of the edge between `a` and `b` in the circular diagram, and `b2` to the right of the edge between `a` and `d`. Using absolute coordinates to increase the distance between the additional nodes / try to place them still results in the circular diagram to the right of both nodes. Can this be done please?

---

My example code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}    
\tikzset{
state/.style={rectangle split, draw=black, text width=3cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]  
  \node [state, rectangle split parts=2] (b1) at (0,5) {text \nodepart{two} one};
  \node [state, rectangle split parts=2] (b2) at (5,5) {text \nodepart{two} two};
\end{tikzpicture}    

\smartdiagram[circular diagram] {a, b, c, d}  

\end{document}
```

---

I thought maybe [TikZ: adding nodes to a circular diagram from smartdiagram package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102857/tikz-adding-nodes-to-a-circular-diagram-from-smartdiagram-package) could help but I can't see how to add the nodes i.e.

```
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{a, b, c, d}{
              left of module1/\node [state, rectangle split parts=2]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smartdiagram` gives the nodes names. You can thus connect them using overlay. The IMHO only less appealing aspect of this is that things drawn in `overlay` mode do not increase the bounding box, which you need to do by hand. This explains the `\hspace*{2cm}` in

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}    
\tikzset{
state/.style={rectangle split, draw=black, text width=3cm}
}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{2cm}\smartdiagram[circular diagram] {a, b, c, d}\hspace*{2cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]  
  \path (module1) -- (module2) node[midway,above left=1cm,state, rectangle split parts=2] (b1) at (0,5) {text \nodepart{two} one};
  \path (module1) -- (module4) node [midway,above right=1cm,state, rectangle split parts=2] (b2) at (5,5) {text \nodepart{two} two};
\end{tikzpicture}    


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , this looks great (I had managed to do something in completely in tikz, but the paths were all just a bit crude i.e. using [`bend right`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100691/tikz-alter-circular-path-with-nodes) -- this looks much better). I hadn't heard of [`overlay`](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/overlays/) but I'll read up Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! (Sometimes `arc`s look better than `bend right`. In principle you can look up all definitions in the very nice manual of `smartdiagram`, which is how I learned that the names `moduleN` with integer `N`, but if the diagram already looks like you want to have it, you may not want to reinvent it. ;-)

Comment: Dear @marmot; apologies for the follow-up I couldn't find how to do this, but how do you increase the vertical space as well i.e.`\hspace*{8cm}\vspace{8cm}` doesn't work.

Comment: ... seems I can accomplish this with `border=50pt` -- but of a hack im sure

Comment: @user20650 another way is `\begin{tabular}{c}
~\\[3cm]
\hspace*{2cm}\smartdiagram[circular diagram] {a, b, c, d}\hspace*{2cm}\\[3cm]
\end{tabular}` ... (also) not too beautiful